# Supporting multiple screens on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

Have read the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)  which is lengthy and still not clear.

Assuming I have an image with size = 120px * 80px, under the default mdpi/160 density, I also need to prepare

```
ldpi = 90 * 60
hdpi = 180 * 120
xhdpi = 240 * 160
```

Are the calculation above right? Assume I only have a single layout, so what I need is to prepare the images and place them under the corresponding drawable folders, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those are the correct sizes.

Yes, just put your various versions in the res/drawable-ldpi, -mdpi, -hdpi, and -xhdpi
folders and you're done.

Depending on your image -- specifically whether it still looks good scaled down automatically -- you could just provide hdpi and xhdpi versions and Android will automatically scale them at run-time for ldpi and mdpi respectively.

Answer (score 3):

The image sizes you have calculated are correct based on the [formula from Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

```
pixels = dp * (density / 160)
```

Knowing the target densities of the various DPIs will allow us to calculate final image sizes:

```
ldpi = 120 DPI
mdpi = 160 DPI
hdpi = 240 DPI
xhdpi = 320 DPI
```

Here would be the correct calculation for width, starting with a medium density asset at 120 pixels wide:

```
ldpi  (120 DPI) = 120 * (120 / 160) == 90
mdpi  (160 DPI) = 120 * (160 / 160) == 120
hdpi  (240 DPI) = 120 * (240 / 160) == 180
xhdpi (320 DPI) = 120 * (320 / 160) == 240
```

Here would be the correct calculation for height, starting with a medium density asset at 80 pixels tall:

```
ldpi  (120 DPI) = 80 * (120 / 160) == 60
mdpi  (160 DPI) = 80 * (160 / 160) == 80
hdpi  (240 DPI) = 80 * (240 / 160) == 120
xhdpi (320 DPI) = 80 * (320 / 160) == 160
```

Making your final images:

```
ldpi = 90 x 60
mdpi = 120 x 80
hdpi = 180 x 120
xhdpi = 240 x 160
```

Create the following folders under **res/** if they don't already exist and drop the correct assets in:

- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-xhdpi

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Ok, the calculations are correct. According to the formula `px = dp * (dpi / 160)` from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, where pixels on mdpi = dp.

And here is some additional information:

Dpi tells you how much dots (pixels) are in 1 inch. But it doesn't tell you how much pixels the screen has in total. So, you can have a device, which has, let's say, 400 pixels width and height and the screen has a diagonal of 5 inches. With this you get the dpi value. (Using http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html for example).

Now you have another, device, which has the same dpi value, but has a higher resolution and it's bigger, for example, 1000 x 1000 pixels and also large diagonale.

If you created an image for the first case, of let's say 200 x 200 pixels, it will occupy half of the screen, but in the second case it will be only 1/5 of the screen, although both devices having same dpi, and that's probably not what you want to do.

What I usually do is orientate on the resolution of devices which *usually* have this dpi (like hdpi -> 480x800, xhdpi -> 720x1280, etc.), and in the layout use dip in combination with scaleType "fitStart", "center", etc. to keep the images proportional. So I put images with different resolutions in ldpi, hdpi and xhdpi folders but I don't use a formula.

There's also the possibility to use screen sizes in combination/instead with dpi, in the case it's necessary:

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

This works with additional folders like dpi.

BTW. Currently it's possible to put different versions of the app in Google Play for different resolutions / screens, so the user doesn't have to download all the files (huge app size, long time downloading, etc.), only the ones necessary for the device.

Comment: The purpose of dpi scaling in Android is for images to have the same _physical size_ on the display regardless of screen pixel density. This scaling is not designed to keep images at the same proportion of the total screen dimensions across devices. As you say, you can use the screen size categories to provide that, but otherwise there's nothing built into Android that is equivalent to pixel density scaling. Note also that as of API 11 (Honeycomb), there is a new way to package resources for different screen sizes.

Comment: Normally, if you use an image as a background or as the source for an ImageView, then the image size will be determined by the view, not by its intrinsic size. However, the intrinsic size (which is measured in pixels) will depend on which density was used when retrieving the image resource. The intrinsic size will be important in cases where the view does not control the image size (e.g., if you use an XML bitmap with android:gravity="center").

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, now I understand. Somehow I associated dip with "screen looking the same" in all devices, and that's not true. The view itself will have the same physical size in all devices, but that doesn't have any relation with the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

the scaling ratio of images for the ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi is 3:4:6:8 but u think once 
1)if there is  mobile with ldpi small screen is there then it will be suitable for the screen.
2)if there is mobile with ldpi medium screen is there then the images appear little bit smaller
3)2)if there is mobile with ldpi large screen is there then the images appear smaller.

like this for all the mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi screens.

If there is chance of using nine patch images in your app try those images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the calculations on the sizes that you have made are **correct.**

Now, you need to put them in the respective folders  of *ldpi* , *mdpi* , *hdpi* and *xhdpi* in *res/drawable* of your project.

Comment: (View size in dp * screen density ) / 160

Comment: @Ixx - Android classifies screens into four categories based on their (approximate) pixel density: ldpi = 120 pixels/inch; mdpi = 160 pixels/inch; hdpi = 240 pixels/inch; xhdpi = 320 pixels/inch. To maintain the same physical size, image pixel dimensions should be scaled according to those ratios.

Comment: @lxx There is a formula for that. See my answer. If you know the screen density and the size of widget in dp, you can calculate the equivalent size in pixels.

Comment: Sorry for deleting the comments. Thought a moment that I'm completly wrong. But now I'm not completly sure, there's something missing in these numbers... see my post. I appreciate if you explain me why I'm wrong, if that's the case.

Comment: I think, what's missing is that the image has to always have a fixed size of 120 * 80 dip (which is the same as pixels in mdpi). Then all the variables in the formula have a value and the pixel size can be calculated. But the thread opener doesn't write that the view will be sized with 120 * 80 dip.

Comment: If these images are to be used for a widget of fixed size, then the formula can be used. Otherwise there is no easy way to maintain the image quality as well as scale it according to our needs. So when the widget size is fixed, irrespective of what device is used, the image will always have the same physical size. It may be the case that it occupies half the screen on a bigger sized device, and 2/3rd of the screen on a medium sized device, but the image will definitely have the same size on both the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct if your goal is for your image to have (approximately) the same physical size on devices of different pixel densities. The images would go in directories

> res/drawable-ldpi
>   res/drawable-mdpi
>   res/drawable-hdpi
>   res/drawable-xhdpi

Android classifies the device into one of these general density classes (which are 120dpi, 160dpi, 240dpi, and 320dpi) and scales images according to those ratios. Since physical devices aren't necessarily exactly one of these densities, the physical size of the image can still vary slightly from device to device. Note that if you don't supply an image for a particular density, Android will generate one by scaling the default/mdpi image. Generally, the result isn't quite to the quality that you would get by providing your own image.

If you run Android Lint, it will tell you about any missing resources (such as forgetting to include a xhdpi image) and it will also tell you if your scaling calculations are substantially off. It's a nice feature to know about.

Note that this entire image scaling approach has nothing to do with screen *size*, only pixel *density*. You can also have resource folders for different screen sizes or even for different screen size/density combinations.

However, if you want an image that will display at 120 x 80 pixels regardless of the screen density, the above scheme won't work. Instead, you should put the image in the folder

> res/drawable-nodpi

Android won't scale images that it retrieves from there. The result is that your image would be about 3/4" x 1/2" on an mdpi device, 1" x 3/4" on an ldpi device, 3/8" x 1/4" on an xhdpi device, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to calculate equivalent size in pixels if you know the screen density(dpi) of the device:

equivalentPixels = sizeInDP*(screenDensity/160)

where sizeinDP is the size of widget where you want to display the image. Calculate the sizes in pixels for various screen densities and put them under respective folders.

So if you have an `ImageView` of size 300dp X 200dp (Width X Height), and the screen density is 320dpi, the image size in pixels should be:

Width = 300*(320/160) = 600px
Height = 200*(320/160) = 400px

Hope this helps!