# am I supposed to make images larger for tablets, or same size as handset?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to wrap my head around the idea of scaling images which is all new to me. I finally understand for icon launcher you want something like 48x48 for mdpi and 72x72 for hdpi. For this, I have no problem using google's provided tool. I have an image I downloaded from the net that is 178x283 pixels, 96 dpi. When my (4inch 480x800hdpi) phone emulator views this, the image is pretty large, taking about half the screen. On my (10inch1280x800mdpi)phone, it looks smaller, actually the exact same as the original. This is not what I want right? how do I want the images to be scaled? do I want them the same size as the original, or smaller on a small phone and bigger on a big phone. I assume after this step I create the correct qualifiers and do the math done in this thread to resize the images ? [Supporting multiple screens on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004197/supporting-multiple-screens-on-android?rq=1). I forgot to mention what does android OS do automatically, because I figured if I have one image in drawable, then it will automatically make the smaller phone have a small image and the bigger phone have a big image, but that is not happening(given that I don't hard code values).

`EDIT:` decided to use this http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

`EDIT2:` I have gotten the images and layouts how I want them now, but my 10 inch won't use the correct layout folder. I have this

```
layout
layout-land
layout-sw720dp
layout-sw720dp-land
```

it only works when i name them layout-xlarge, which is deprecated, what gives

`edit`:is it because sw qualifier is only for 3.3+ and I am targeting 2.3+?

Comment: Only you can determine what you want; if it doesn't look like you expected or desire then no it's not right. I believe with many images it's easier to use a tool like photoshop or similar to re-size them  and provide the appropriate one for each definition.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the images to scale? Or do you want them to stay a particular size.

If you want them to scale, you can use something like this in your layout

```
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Then set your size however you want with either layout_width or maxWidth (and length respectively).

Then scale how you want to:

```
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

If the images are pixelated, then you need to add larger images for each screen size under your res folder.

Comment: Right now I already have adjustviewbounds true and use wrap_content for everything or match_parent. I read its bad practice to hard code values so I do not want to do that unless its the only way. I think I have scalefitstart for landscape. The issue is that the large phone the image is tiny, and the small phone the image is large. If it is autosizing it for me, why is it so small on the large tablet

Comment: Because it is wrapping the content... more pixels, smaller image, less pixels, bigger image.It is bad practice to hard code certain values, but layouts should not be an issue when it comes to certain things... like for example, textSizes, etc. Unless you want to programmatically set the size to a particular screen percentage.

Comment: You can also put a different sized image into your drawables-mdpi, hdpi, etc folders.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different layout for 10 inches tablet and another for 7 inches tablet then use this code below:

```
     DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

            final int height = dm.heightPixels;
            final int width = dm.widthPixels;

          if ((height == 1280) && (width == 800)) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.10inchLayout);
                    }else if ((heig

ht == 1024) && (width == 600)) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.7inchLayout);
                }

                 else {
                    setContentView(R.layout.PhoneinchLayout);
                }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am currently not that far in learning android, I am going through a uber slow coursera course lol. I am looking for a simple way to make my 10 inch mdpi use bigger images, I've tried drawables-sw600dp and sw600dp-mdpi, but it always has such a tiny image.

Comment: I don not think this is a good idea to identify a 10" or 7" screen using the height and width. Since Nexus 7 2013 (7") is 1920x1080 on a 7". @Immanuel - your method would simply fail. A better approach is to use resource folder, like `layout-sw600dp` for 7" and `layout-sw720dp` for 10". See a detailed explanation here - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: @Varun ye it might not be a good approach as there so many device out there with different screen size u can use this code to get the most popular sizes and what u suggested will work as well will use that in my future android apps