# How to can I create an image that can be used for different android screen sizes?

Tags: android

I created an image to use for an android splash screen and it displays properly on my phone however when I open the app on a phone with a larger screen it pixelates. So I was wonder if I should create more than one image and if so what sizes should I set for other images because I know I can't use the same sizes as I used for the app icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could probably use draw-9-patch to state which area of the picture can be extended.

[Google draw-9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the images are pixelated

- then you need to add larger images for each screen size under your
  res folder. sizes depends on your target

or

- scale the images. to be safe, make it bigger

it might help you: [am I supposed to make images larger for tablets, or same size as handset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644523/am-i-supposed-to-make-images-larger-for-tablets-or-same-size-as-handset)

Answer (score 0):

I worked with two approaches so far:

**Screen composition**

One approach can be using a composition of brackground and a logo. You can have the logo as big as you need (for high resolution screens) and the background as a repeatable texture (it all depends on your design approach) or a gradient or other composition (less prone to pixelation errors).

**As big as possible approach**

If one image is your approach, you should do a research to know the currently most used and biggest android screen used (https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Knowing that one, you can design your image for that [high] resolution and set the scaleType as CENTER_CROP. With that, you will ensure that the image will be centered, inside the screen, keeping aspect ratio, and at its highest resolution [keep an eye about logos/graphics positions if you want to be sure that they remain visible even in thin screens).

Answer (score 0):

For icons, the best way is [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Otherwise, you need to scale the images into `drawable-xx` (res directory), [here the explanation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)